# Can't label the dots in the dotplot

Tags: r, lattice

I have some multivariate data.

I want to draw a dotplot for this data, so I wrote the following code:.

```
a.data <- read.table("C:/Users/OGR001/Documents/veri2.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)


useOuterStrips(dotplot(reliability ~ factor(madde.sayisi) |  
                                    as.factor(orneklem)*as.factor(yontem),
                       groups=as.factor(formul),  
                       data=a.data, as.table=TRUE, 
                       horizontal=FALSE, 
                       jitter.x=TRUE))
```

The dotplot is ok, but I want to name the dots here.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example please.

Comment: "I want to name the dots here.", do you mean add a label for each dot ? which labels?

Comment: Yes agstudy, I want to add labels (sb, r, f) for the dots. They represent my dependent variable "formul", and this variable has 3 categories, the categories are sb, r and f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a reproducible example, it is really hard to help you! I answer just because  it is a little bit challenging to custom panel of a lattice plot.  basically you need to add this line :

```
            panel=function(x,y,...){
                 panel.dotplot(x,y,...)
                 labs <- dat[list(...)$subscripts,]$labs ## labs is your factor column!
                 panel.text(x,y,labs,adj=c(1.2,0.5))
               }))
```

For example, Here using `barley` from the lattice package.

```
dat <- barley
dat$labs <- sample(c('SB','R','F'),nrow(dat),rep=T)

useOuterStrips(dotplot(variety ~ yield | site*year, 
                       data = dat,
                       groups = year,
                       horizontal=TRUE, 
                       jitter.x=TRUE,  ylab=NULL,
               panel=function(x,y,...){
                 panel.dotplot(x,y,...)
                 labs <- dat[list(...)$subscripts,]$labs
                 panel.text(x,y,labs,adj=c(1.2,0.5))
               }))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. Now I'm studying agstudy's answer, I don't know some of the codes. I didn't understand the codes begining with "panel". So I'm trying to understand the meaning of these x,y,list(...),$subscripts etc. I'm very new and need time to analyze the codes. When I solve, I'll write the news here.

Comment: @user2123601 if you are new to R , understanding lattice panel functions it is not the most easier thing. But does this answer , is waht you are looking for?

Comment: Ok, I used the codes and it works great. I understood how the codes work. Thank you very much for your help. :))

Answer (score 1):

The car package allows easy labeling of dots in a scatterplot. We can use the iris dataset for illustration.

```
library(car)
scatterplot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data=iris,labels=iris$Species,id.method=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit: agstudy is correct that you can't use base graphics on a lattice window.  Luckily theres a `ltext` command that does basically the same thing, so use `ltext` in the manner described below for base graphics'  `text` .

Dunno what's easiest, but `base::text` certainly can do this. I'm going to assume you can use a factor or a column in your dataframe to select the `sb` , `r`, and `f` coordinate sets separately.  so:

```
text(sb_x_coords, sb_y_coords, labels='sb',...)
```

where you can mod the fontsize, color, etc.
Repeat for the other two categories.